# Simplifying a covariance expression

Tags: probability, covariance, matrix, covariance-matrix

Let $I=\begin{pmatrix}I_1\\\vdots\\ I_n
\end{pmatrix}$ be a random vector, and $\Omega$ and $\Omega_I$ two random variables. I am trying to simplify the following equation (which worth $\frac{\rho_{I\Omega_I} \rho_{I\Omega}}{\rho_{\Omega\Omega_I}}$ if $I$ is a random variable):

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{\operatorname{Cov}(\Omega,\Omega_I)}}_{\mathrm{scalar}}\underbrace{\operatorname{Cov}(I,\Omega_I)}_{(n,1)}\underbrace{\operatorname{Cov}(\Omega,I)}_{(1,n)}\underbrace{V(I)^{-1}}_{(n,n)}=?$$

Does anyone know how to simplify this expression that should be an $(n,n)$ matrix?

Comment: Could you please indicate what kind of form you would consider to be "simpler" than this expression?  It is a very compact combination of four separate things that have, at best, only weak mathematical constraints among them, making one wonder how it could possibly be any simpler than it already is.

Comment: I have rewritten my problem this way: Let $I=\begin{pmatrix}I_1\\\vdots\\ I_n
\end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}X_1\\\vdots\\ X_p
\end{pmatrix}$ be two random vectors and $\Omega_I$ a random variable. I am looking for A such that:
$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{V(\Omega_I)}}_{Scalar}\underbrace{Cov(X,I)}_{(p,n)}\underbrace{V(I)^{-1}}_{(n,n)}\underbrace{Cov(I,\Omega_I)}_{(n,1)}=A \underbrace{\frac{1}{V(\Omega_I)}}_{Scalar}\underbrace{Cov(X,\Omega_I)}_{(p,1)}$$

When X et I are random variables, $A=\frac{\rho_{XI}\rho_{I\Omega_I}}{\rho_{X\Omega_I}}$.

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect the changes indicated in your comment.  But without any stated relationship between $\Omega_I$ and $I,$ why should any such $A$ exist?